# how to make '' AND "" syntax highlight strings for python in notepad++?

Tags: python, string, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

Currently I have only "doubleQuotes" highlighted but the 'single ones' stay normal.
Can someone confirm? Or have a solution how to fix that?

In the `stylers.xml` there is WordsStyle named STRING which has the "doubleQuote" color. But neither there nor in the `langs.xml` I'm able to see a way to make it work for 'singleQuotes' too. Or at least I know too little to about configuring those Notepad++ files.

Please don't suggest another editor ;] thx!

Comment: go to `language` in the top manu and make sure `python` is selected

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: didn't know the page. Here are similar questions where you didn't suggest this yet. ;]

Comment: @IonutHulub: is already triggered by .py extension :/
Also: The python specific coloring for "doubleQuotes" works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default language styling that comes with Notepad++:

- **'single'** quotes are controlled by the **CHARACTER** Style
- **"double"** ones by **STRING**.

Comment: Seems there is no way to unify them tho :/. However. Works properly now.

Answer (score 1):

on the menu bar, select settings / Style Configurator / Python.
then work on the TRIPLE and TRIPLEDOUBLE settings.

Comment: hmm.. No. What you mean does the '''comment block stuff''' thats used for .__doc__ Thats all set up properly.